# Touch-screen <canvas> for signatures not working on touch-screen devices

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The canvas signing works with mouse but isn't working with mobile. What am I missing?

When I use the canvas on my computer, the mouse-draw feature works well but when I open the file via mobile, the signature pad doesn't work. I have looked through my code but I can't identify the problem. Any ideas?

The HTML:

```
<!--The Signature Pad & Clear Button-->

<canvas id="sketchpad" width="500" height="200" style="background-color:#C4C4C4"></canvas>

<button type="button" value="Clear Sketchpad" id="clearbutton" onclick="clearCanvas(canvas,ctx);">Clear</button>
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Variables for referencing the canvas and 2dcanvas context

var canvas,ctx;

// Variables to keep track of the mouse position and left-button status 

var mouseX,mouseY,mouseDown=0;

// Variables to keep track of the touch position

var touchX,touchY;

// Draws a dot at a specific position on the supplied canvas name

// Parameters are: A canvas context, the x position, the y position, the size of the dot

function drawDot(ctx,x,y,size) {

    // Let's use black by setting RGB values to 0, and 255 alpha (completely opaque)

    r=0; g=0; b=0; a=255;

    // Select a fill style

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+(a/255)+")";

    // Draw a filled circle

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 

    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.fill();
} 

// Clear the canvas context using the canvas width and height

function clearCanvas(canvas,ctx) {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

// Keep track of the mouse button being pressed and draw a dot at current location

function sketchpad_mouseDown() {

    mouseDown=1;

    drawDot(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,4);
}

// Keep track of the mouse button being released

function sketchpad_mouseUp() {

    mouseDown=0;
}

// Kepp track of the mouse position and draw a dot if mouse button is currently pressed

function sketchpad_mouseMove(e) { 

    // Update the mouse co-ordinates when moved

    getMousePos(e);

    // Draw a dot if the mouse button is currently being pressed

    if (mouseDown==1) {

        drawDot(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,4);
    }
}

// Get the current mouse position relative to the top-left of the canvas

function getMousePos(e) {
    if (!e)
        var e = event;

    if (e.offsetX) {
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
    }
    else if (e.layerX) {
        mouseX = e.layerX;
        mouseY = e.layerY;
    }
 }

// Draw something when a touch start is detected

function sketchpad_touchStart() {

    // Update the touch co-ordinates

    getTouchPos();

    drawDot(ctx,touchX,touchY,4);

    // Prevents an additional mousedown event being triggered

    event.preventDefault();
}

// Draw something and prevent the default scrolling when touch movement is detected

function sketchpad_touchMove(e) { 

    // Update the touch co-ordinates

    getTouchPos(e);

    // During a touchmove event, unlike a mousemove event, we don't need to check if the touch is engaged, since there will always be contact with the screen by definition.

    drawDot(ctx,touchX,touchY,4); 

    // Prevent a scrolling action as a result of this touchmove triggering.

    event.preventDefault();
}

// Get the touch position relative to the top-left of the canvas

// When we get the raw values of pageX and pageY below, they take into account the scrolling on the page

// but not the position relative to our target div. We'll adjust them using "target.offsetLeft" and

// "target.offsetTop" to get the correct values in relation to the top left of the canvas.

function getTouchPos(e) {

    if (!e)

        var e = event;


    if(e.touches) {

        if (e.touches.length == 1) { // Only deal with one finger

            var touch = e.touches[0]; // Get the information for finger #1

            touchX=touch.pageX-touch.target.offsetLeft;

            touchY=touch.pageY-touch.target.offsetTop;
        }
    }
}


// Set-up the canvas and add our event handlers after the page has loaded

function init() {

    // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document

    canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');

    // If the browser supports the canvas tag, get the 2d drawing context for this canvas

    if (canvas.getContext)

        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Check that we have a valid context to draw on/with before adding event handlers

    if (ctx) {

        // React to mouse events on the canvas, and mouseup on the entire document

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);

        window.addEventListener('mouseup', sketchpad_mouseUp, false);

        // React to touch events on the canvas

        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', sketchpad_touchStart, false);

        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', sketchpad_touchMove, false);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What mobile browser? Chrome? Safari? IE? All of them?

Comment: It isn't working on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this buy removing the "position:relative;" from the parent div of canvas.